# Vue.js does not get mqtt response message

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, mqtt

I am really new to Vue and for this project I am trying to pass default value to `Vue data return()` . Currently it prints out the `console.log('INSIDE CLIENT ON MESSAGE")`. But the value defined as  `this.room1status = 1`, does not get passed or updated to `data return room1status`. Is there a way that I can pass value 1 to `room1status` of vue, once its inside `client.on('message', function (topic, message)` ?

**Script**

```
  data(){
    return{
      room1status: ''
      }
   },

  mounted: function(){
    var mqtt = require('mqtt')
    var client  = mqtt.connect('ws://myUrl/')

    client.on('connect', function () {
      client.subscribe('route_status', function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
        }
      })
    })

    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {

      var filterData = message;
      var x = JSON.parse(filterData);
      console.log('INSIDE CLIENT ON MESSAGE"); /** prints this out succesfully **/
      this.room1status = 1; /** but this does not get passed or updated to data return room1status **/
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the `on` function callback doesn't refer to the component instance, so you should assign `this` to a variable `vm` before call that callback then use it inside it :

```
  var vm=this;
  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {

      var filterData = message;
      var x = JSON.parse(filterData);
      console.log('INSIDE CLIENT ON MESSAGE"); 
      vm.room1status = 1; 
    }
```